# How do I override recurring text/strings with icons/images?

Tags: media

I'm not sure this is possible or if there is a module that does this already, that's why I am asking :) Think of [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides/) except to turn strings into an image.

I ran into the module [Iconify](http://drupal.org/project/iconify) which basically adds icons to the admin config headings, and I was wondering if there is a way to use icons/images to replace specific recurring strings. For example:
Say I would like to change the "View" link on the Page content type into an icon of an eye. Or the "Edit" link into a little pencil.

How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal allows you to override almost anything and what you are referring to here is the theme()ing of various pieces.  In your specific example, 'View' and 'Edit' are tabs/local tasks on a node page, and they are themed something like this in Drupal 6:

```
/**
 * Generate the HTML output for a single local task link.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
function theme_menu_local_task($link, $active = FALSE) {
  return '<li '. ($active ? 'class="active" ' : '') .'>'. $link ."</li>\n";
}
```

and this in Drupal 7:

```
/**
 * Returns HTML for a single local task link.
 *
 * @param $variables
 *   An associative array containing:
 *   - element: A render element containing:
 *     - #link: A menu link array with 'title', 'href', and 'localized_options'
 *       keys.
 *     - #active: A boolean indicating whether the local task is active.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
function theme_menu_local_task($variables) {
  $link = $variables['element']['#link'];
  $link_text = $link['title'];

  if (!empty($variables['element']['#active'])) {
    // Add text to indicate active tab for non-visual users.
    $active = '<span class="element-invisible">' . t('(active tab)') . '</span>';

    // If the link does not contain HTML already, check_plain() it now.
    // After we set 'html'=TRUE the link will not be sanitized by l().
    if (empty($link['localized_options']['html'])) {
      $link['title'] = check_plain($link['title']);
    }
    $link['localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;
    $link_text = t('!local-task-title!active', array('!local-task-title' => $link['title'], '!active' => $active));
  }

  return '<li' . (!empty($variables['element']['#active']) ? ' class="active"' : '') . '>' . l($link_text, $link['href'], $link['localized_options']) . "</li>\n";
}
```

So, to change this from text to a graphic, you would create a theme function of your own in your theme's template.php file:

```
function YOURTHEME_menu_local_task(....
```

that looked at either `$link` or `$variables['#link']` and output an image instead of the text.

And if php isn't your forte, but jQuery is, you could also do it in the browser with something like:

```
$('.tabs a[href$="edit"]').html('<img src="edit.jpg">');
```

which would replace the text of your edit link with an image.  If you went this route you would put this in a suitable drupal behavior wrapper in your theme or custom module as well.

Comment: Interesting, thanks a lot for the detailed response. It seems this is a little beyond me at this point though. I think I may have a look at other themes that look similar to what I want to achieve and see how they are doing what you've detailed above.